# возможен ли рефакторинг в отдельном фрагменте php кода?

Tags: php

```
//создается соединение с бд
$connection = ConnectionManager::Get()->getConnectionDatabase(); 
        //без коментов
        $sql = 'SELECT `login`,`email` FROM `users` WHERE `id`>=1';
        $q = $connection->query($sql);
        $a = array();
        $i = 1;
        //меня интересует именно этот участок кода из while (мысли по етому поводу под кодом)
        while($x = $connection->fetch($q)){
            $a[$i]['login'] = $x['login'];
            $a[$i]['email'] = $x['email'];
            $i++;
        }
        $this->setValue('names', $a); // -> отправляем в smarty
```

пример того что получаю по запросу

```
array(4) { [1]=> array(2) {
               ["login"]=> string(5) "admin" 
               ["email"]=> string(21) "dp0309@gmail.com" 
         }
            [2]=> array(2) { 
               ["login"]=> string(4) "igor" 
               ["email"]=> string(14) "dp03@gmail.com" 
         } 
            [3]=> array(2) { 
                ["login"]=> string(5) "amin2" 
                ["email"]=> string(15) "hello@gmail.com" 
         }  [4]=> array(2) { 
                ["login"]=> string(6) "amin22" 
                ["email"]=> string(16) "hello2@gmail.com" 
         } }
```

после получения хочу их завернуть в массив и отправить в smarty для отрисовки. Участок кода из while не очень нравится, потому как если я захочу сделать выборку шире, нужно будет добавлять
`$a[$i]['thomething'] = $x['thomething'];`

Можно как то изменить это?;

Спасибо.

Comment: какой фреймворк вы используете? или это самописный код?

Comment: @boris_U Да можно сказать это самописный код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно вот так у меня сделано с использованием базовых функция mysql.

```
function db_fetch($db_handle, $result)  {
    if ( $db_handle != null && $result != null ) {
        $data = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            while (list ($key, $val) = each ($row)) {
                    $data[$i][$key] = $val;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

В вашем случае - надо понимать, что и в каком виде возвращает `$connection->fetch($q)`

Comment: Прошу прощения, но такой код - это ужас.. Хотя бы PDO-использовали, а в идеале - какой-нибудь внятный ORM.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: ну ужас-не ужас - а исправно работает с 2001 года.

Comment: @boris_U вот в свежих версиях PHP уже давно не работает. Да и между "работает десять лет" и "работает год" предпочту второе даже в рамках ПО.

Comment: @boris_U, ну тем не менее, если использовать ORM, то получилось бы более приятное глазу `$users = $database->table('users')->where('id >=1');`. И да, ваш код не работает "из коробки" в современных версиях PHP, а если принудительно поставить расширение - выдаёт кучу предупреждений о том, что эти функции устарели и в следующих версиях их не будет совсем. И да, в PHP 7 их нет и не планируется, даже как отдельные модуль - только PDO для общения с базой. )

Comment: @Etki: PHP 5.4.41-0+deb7u1 - достаточно свежая версия?

Comment: @boris_U, нет, это технический релиз поддержки старой версии. 5.5 вышел более двух лет назад, осенью семерка выходит.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: PDO - отстой! Ну, то-есть, по качеству работы с MySQL он очень-очень, от слова ОЧЕНЬ, проигрывает связке mysqlnd+mysqli. Единственная польза от него - это более-менее безболезненный порт с MySQL на PgSQL(или обратно). mysqli - рекомендуют сами разработчики PHP. Код, приведенный мною в ответе, портируется на mysqli нажатием 1 клавиши - "i". И да - мой код работает из коробки - надо уметь брать нужные коробки.

Comment: @boris_U, и в чем же выражается это "качество" и "очень-ОЧЕНЬ"? Удосужитесь описать пожалуйста ) Будет крайне занимательно об этом послушать ))

Answer (score 2):

Что мешает написать `$a[$i] = $x`, если данные отдаются всего лишь в Smarty, где будут очень скоро использованы и позабыты?

Comment: Допишите, пожалуйста, что данные передаются по значению, поэтому нет вообще никакого смысла делать иначе. Я просто не имею морального права настолько глубоко редактировать чей-то ответ.

Comment: Не вижу смысла разделять передачу по значению и по ссылке когда само присваивание делается по значению (т.е. копирующее)

Comment: Я не про разделять. Я про то, что предложенный вариант со всех точек зрения абсолютно безопасен.

Comment: Он был бы опасен, если бы данные потом кодировались в JSON и отправлялись браузеру. Он безопасен, потому что данные остаются на сервере. При чем тут передача по значению - не понимаю.

Comment: При том, что автор, видимо, боится, что простое присваивание скопирует ссылки на данные (иначе я не могу объяснить этот алгоритм).

Comment: Автор просто решал задачу о чайнике.

Comment: кстати ваша рекоментация отличная, но вопрос был о другом.